# Adding a new section with rows at the top of a UITableView (for recently added)

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `UIViewController` which contains a `UITableView`, I generate my desired datasource and put them in my table with no problems.
What I want is when I fetch new data from my server, I want to show them at the top of the existing tableview in a section called "Recently added".
  Note that this new section's number of rows may vary depending on what comes from server.

What I need to know is how and where I should put some code to do such thing. Should it be in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath` which I already have some cells being dequeued there?
Or somewhere else.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

P.S: I understand that with `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` I only have access to the visible cells on screen and I cant wait until all the tableView is loaded.

Comment: Don't forget to mark top answer and upvote the answer(s) that helped you. Others facing the same issue will want to know what solved it and those putting in the time to answer will appreciate the rep points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath
```

Is where you create the cells you want to display, so the user opens the screen, this callback is called X times and the cells are added in.

If you are creating a system, where for example, every 10 seconds a server is checked and new data downloaded. You would then presumably create the new cells and then call something like:

```
tableview insertRowsAtIndexPaths:<#(NSArray *)#> withRowAnimation:<#(UITableViewRowAnimation)#>
```

and then update your data source or you could update your datasource and call a reload so it will re run the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath` callback, with `[tableView reloadData]`

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick answer, can I ask to see the above answer's comment by me and respond to that. Thanks for the time ;)

Comment: @Mepla yes, so inside your code you should have say an array of section titles and an dictionary of cell data (data for each section). When you fetch your results, you should update both of these objects and reload the tableView. Then the callbacks will be re-triggered. So numberOfSectionsInTableView, should return the count of the array of sections titles, the callback for numberOfRowsForIndexPath, should return the count of data items in the dictionary element for that section etc etc

Answer (score 1):

You should

1. Update your data source. I mean the data you use to show in your `UITableView`.
2. Generate the corresponding `NSIndexPath` for rows and sections to be inserted.
3. Call `insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` to insert the rows and sections.

You can do this after you fetch data from server and note to do this in main thread.

Example code:

```
//discountArray contains data fetched from server.
[self.discountArray addObjectsFromArray:discountArray];

// Here I use my category to generate an array of NSIndexPath.
NSArray *indexPathArray = [NSIndexPath indexPathsFrom:self.discountArray.count - discountArray.count
                                                   to:self.discountArray.count
                                            inSection:0];
// Insert the rows with animation.
[self.discountListTableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPathArray withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. So I should change my number of rows and sections when I get the new fetched? I mean like adding an `if (thereIsFetchedContent)` and then change the number of sections by 1 and number of rows depending on the content? or am I getting it all wrong?